# Virtual host in Apache Zend

Tags: apache, virtualhost, windows

I'd like to ask you if you can tell me why I can't get Vhost in Apache to work my Vhostconf is:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "E:/Archivos de programa/Zend/Apache2/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
<Directory "E:/Archivos de programa/Zend/Apache2/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
#AllowOveride all
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis           documentos/NetBeansProjects/HealingHands"
ServerName healinghands.loc
<Directory "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects/HealingHands">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects/HealingHands/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects/HealingHands/logs/access.log" common
#AllowOveride all
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
DocumentRoot "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects"
ServerName dev.loc
<Directory "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
ErrorLog "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects/logs/error.log"
CustomLog "E:/Documents and Settings/dvieira/Mis documentos/NetBeansProjects/logs/access.log" common
#AllowOveride all
</VirtualHost>
```

My *httpd.conf* is:

```
ServerRoot "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\Apache2"

Listen  80

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule auth_digest_module modules/mod_auth_digest.so
LoadModule authn_default_module modules/mod_authn_default.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_default_module modules/mod_authz_default.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule imagemap_module modules/mod_imagemap.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule info_module modules/mod_info.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule userdir_module modules/mod_userdir.so
<IfModule !mpm_netware_module>
<IfModule !mpm_winnt_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
ServerAdmin admin@example.com

DocumentRoot "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\Apache2/htdocs"
<Directory />
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
<IfModule dir_module>
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html home.php
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn
<IfModule log_config_module>
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" common
<IfModule logio_module>
  LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\" %I %O" combinedio
</IfModule>
    CustomLog "logs/access.log" common
</IfModule>
<IfModule alias_module>

 Alias /NetBeansProjects "E:\Documents and Settings\dvieira\Mis documentos\NetBeansProjects"  

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\Apache2/cgi-bin/"
</IfModule>
<IfModule cgid_module>

</IfModule>

<Directory "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\Apache2/cgi-bin">
AllowOverride None
Options None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>


DefaultType text/plain
<IfModule mime_module>

TypesConfig conf/mime.types

AddType application/x-compress .Z
AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz

</IfModule>


Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf

<IfModule ssl_module>
SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>
Include "conf/zend.conf"

NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>

Include "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\ZendServer/etc/sites.d/zend-default-vhost-80.conf"

</VirtualHost>

Include "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\ZendServer/etc/sites.d/globals-*.conf"
Include "E:\Archivos de programa\Zend\ZendServer/etc/sites.d/vhost_*.conf"
```

And my host in Windows:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       healinghands.loc
127.0.0.1       dev.loc
```

And I can't get any of the browser to recognize *dev.loc* or *healinghands.loc* but a ping does it. Localhost is working fine.

I've spent 3 days now traying to solve this for my one but I finally quit and have to ask.

The error should be this `Error Code 11002: host not found`. Background: this error indicates that the gateway could not find an authoritative DNS server for the website you are trying to access. Date: 5/20/2013 5:51:03 PM Server: Source: DNS problem.

i'd like to add this ping

```
Haciendo ping a healinghands.loc [127.0.0.1] con 32 bytes de datos:

Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128
Respuesta desde 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 tiempo<1m TTL=128

Estadísticas de ping para 127.0.0.1:
    Paquetes: enviados = 4, recibidos = 4, perdidos = 0
    (0% perdidos),
Tiempos aproximados de ida y vuelta en milisegundos:
    Mínimo = 0ms, Máximo = 0ms, Media = 0ms
```

Today i've tryed something: i've add this domains into the exceptions of mi ie proxy config. This worked for healinghands.loc but not for dev.loc i really do not understand why, both config are exactly the same except for de documentroot. I will continue searching

Answer (score 1):

I didn't realize that if I don't have any index I had to add "Indexes" in option like this

```
<Directory />
    #Options FollowSymLinks
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're configuring vhosts in separated conf file, you've also to include that file (remove comment near the end of httpd.conf file), uncomment

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```